# Delphi 10 always show Script error and Security Alert when first load

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

When I first load RAD studio , will show below two error messages, how to avoid them?

[image]
[image]

Comment: @KenWhite updated

Comment: try to turn of certificate revocation check in internet options - advanced settings

Answer (score 3):

Removing the Community toolbar
"delphi security alert there is a problem with the site's security certificate vmware , ..."

this help is From "David Millington"

Discription Solve Problem :

Removing the package

This method is the most straightforward and easy.

1-Close the IDE

2-In Explorer, navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin

3-Locate ‘CommunityToolbar250.bpl’

4-Rename it to ‘CommunityToolbar250.bpl.old’

5-Start the IDE.

[Change File name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysJJQ.png)

**Editing the registry**

Editing the registry can damage your system. Take care.

1-Close the IDE

2-Open the registry editor (regedit)

3-Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\19.0\Known IDE Packages

4-Locate the entry, ‘$(BDS)\Bin\CommunityToolbar250.bpl’ with a value of ‘Embarcadero Community Toolbar Package’

5-Edit the string value (not the name, but the textual description of the package), and prepend two underscores, so that the value is ‘__Embarcadero Community Toolbar Package’

6-Start the IDE.

[Edit Registery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/733xH.png)

This error occurred when activating version 10.2.3

Comment: I did not get the security error but I did get script errors (quite a few) and this fixed the problem in 10.2.3

Answer (score 2):

No need to mess around with files or registry entries. Just go to menu **View**, select **Toolbars** and disable the **Embarcadero Community** option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's healthy to be changing settings in the installation of delphi, renaming files or something like that.

So, after some research, I actually found an option that works.

on windows, in internet options -> security -> Custom level -> Display mixed content -> leave the option as "Enable"

apply the new settings and restart delphi.

For version XE8 solved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem that way :

https://community.norton.com/en/system/files/u9996421/ie%20certificates.PNG

Answer (score 0):

you find "$(BDS)\Bin\startpageide260.bpl" for delphi 20.0 version.

You change value with "__Start Page IDE Package".